# Web-api and Kestrel get a null connection when accessing local MySql server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, centos, asp.net-core-webapi

Running DotNet-Core 2.2 Web-Api as a service on Centos box

I am getting Value cannot be null in my configure service method

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<nameOfContextContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevDatabase")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

    }
```

Value cannot be null is at AddDbContext line

Here is my appsettings.json

```
{  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DevDatabase": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=nameOfDatabse;Uid=svcUser;Pwd=Password;"}, "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"}   },"AllowedHosts": "*"}
```

I tried to fix the format hope you can read it.

Anyhow the service runs fine when not using database but as soon as I try to connect to database I get Value cannot be null

Please Help

Comment: "Null object is AddDbContext line", what? Can you rewrite that to make it a proper statement? "null object" is a contradiction, either it's null or it's an object

Comment: Sorry I'll run it again and get the exact error

Comment: Value cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

My appsettings.json is what was/is null.  I believe it is a path error and which dll I am running but the fact of the matter is.

```
        services.AddDbContext<nameOfContextContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(add database connection string here));
```

and viola we have a winner.  I was thinking the connection string was wrong but it's just the configuration file could not be found by kestrel..

PLEASE KEEP IN MIND THIS IS PROBABLY NOT SAFE FOR PRODUCTION.

I am planning to control the creds for database access later